# Multiple drop down list change each overs Tables C# and MySql query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, concatenation

OK I have 2 Drop down list that effect each over when select, if user selects France from `ddlcountry` then `DdPetPist` is populated with `France_Animals` Table and when selects UK or Germany it populates with either the UK table or Germany table. this works well.
problem is I have a label print out displaying two things the `price` and `stock` pulled from UK_Animals table. 
How can I alter my Table query to display the `stock` and `price` depending on the animal chosen at the moment if user selects dog it will show info but only for dogs in UK. I need it so this label changes with the country table.

**The Two DropDown Lists**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MySqlCommand cd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Country", cs); // need to make it so changes database
            cs.Open();
            MySqlDataReader ddlCountry = cd2.ExecuteReader();
            ddlcountry.DataSource = ddlCountry;
            ddlcountry.DataValueField = "Country";
            ddlcountry.DataTextField = "Country";
            ddlcountry.DataBind();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();

            MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UK_Animals", cs);
            cs.Open();
            MySqlDataReader ddlSpecie = cd.ExecuteReader();
            DdPetPist.DataSource = ddlSpecie;
            DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
            DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
            DdPetPist.DataBind();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Code That Changes The Table When different Country Is Selected**

```
 protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlcountry.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}_Animals", ddlcountry.Text), cs);
            cs.Open();
            MySqlDataReader ddlSpecie = cd.ExecuteReader();
            DdPetPist.DataSource = ddlSpecie;
            DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
            DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
            DdPetPist.DataBind();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Code That Changes label Depending On Animal Selects (***But Dose Not Change To Animal Table***)**
This Is What I cant get to Change to Cosponsoring Country Selection It remains Always In UK, I know why but do not Know How to Fix Its So It Changes With The Country Selection.

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selection_price = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
        string selection_stock = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
        string petPrice = string.Empty;
        string available = string.Empty;

        MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Specie_Price FROM UK_Animals WHERE Specie ='{0}'", selection_price), cs);
        MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Stock FROM UK_Animals WHERE Specie ='{0}'", selection_stock), cs);

         cs.Open();
             petPrice = Convert.ToString(cd_price.ExecuteScalar());
             available = Convert.ToString(cd_available.ExecuteScalar());
         cs.Close();

        PetPrice.Text = String.Format("Minimum Donation For A {0}  Is £{1}.", selection_price, petPrice);
        Availble.Text = String.Format("{0}'s Avalible {1}.", selection_stock, available);
    }
```

Please is there a way to do this and if so how?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` point to `UK_Animals` and thus the selection of the table of a different country you do in `ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged` does not have any effect when writing to the labels.

As far as `DdPetPist.DataSource` is updated with the right country information, you should access this variable from `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged`, instead of connecting to the DB again. Alternatively, you might keep the connection to the DB by selecting the table of the corresponding country; but this option does not sound too right: it would involve not-completely-necessary DB connections and global variables.

UPDATE

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selection_price = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
    string selection_stock = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
    string petPrice = string.Empty;
    string available = string.Empty;

    MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Specie_Price FROM {0}_Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_price), cs);
    MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Stock FROM {0}_Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_stock), cs);

    cs.Open();
    petPrice = Convert.ToString(cd_price.ExecuteScalar());
    available = Convert.ToString(cd_available.ExecuteScalar());
    cs.Close();

    PetPrice.Text = String.Format("Minimum Donation For A {0}  Is £{1}.", selection_price, petPrice);
    Availble.Text = String.Format("{0}'s Avalible {1}.", selection_stock, available);
}
```

This is the "option 2"; the best option is adapting these queries to read from the local copy of the table of the given country, stored in `DdPetPist.DataSource`.

Comment: Thank you i shall give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: @Beep OK. I look forward to you reply.

Comment: OK I understand what you are saying, I will fix it so I do not repeat the connection string. the two query's in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` is there a way to write them so it adjusts with the selection of a different country, or would I need to write separate query's for each country and have a if else statement to change accordingly.

Comment: @Beep Actually, there is a pretty straightforward way: when you select the country the DataSource of DdPetPist is updated to the right table. That is, when you are in DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged, DdPetPist actually contains all the animals in the target country, isn't it? Cannot you see the animals of the country you selected updated in the combobox?

Comment: @Beep let me update my answer such that you understand what I mean clearly.

Comment: Thank you @varocarbas. the second drop down DdPetPist does update but then when I select the pet from the updated drop down the query will only show the data for all pets in the UK_Animal table. is there a way to change this query so that it changes the table in the query to the selected country's table.

Comment: @Beep I have included the code to perform the querying as sofar with the right Table.

Comment: @Beep but, as said, this not the ideal approach. The ideal approach is not querying the DB again, but the Table of the given country which you have stored under DdPetPist.DataSource

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried something similar to your answer but it did not work for me before, I understand where I went wrong now due to your help, thanks again.